# How write right ORDER BY ... DESC in SQL select?

Tags: mysql

*Good day.*

Check structure of table [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9ab4/2).

I would like to select:

```
select `idn` order by sum DESC,
where sum = (value amount where type = marks and status = up) - (value amount where type = marks and status = down)
```

For this I use SQL:

```
select idn from Balans as outerB WHERE idn ! = '' group by idn order by 
ifnull((select sum(innerB.amount) from Balans as innerB 
    where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
    and type='up'), 0) -
ifnull((select sum(innerB.amount) from Balans as innerB 
    where innerB.idn = outerB.idn 
    and type='down'), 0) DESC
limit 5
```

But in SQL not make right `ORDER by ... DESC`

For instance in my example result should been:

```
187113012

6299927
```

Test SQL may be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9ab4/2)

Please tell me how to write right SQL select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `CASE` ?

```
  SELECT idn,
         (SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'marks' AND status = 'up' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)-
         SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'marks' AND status = 'down' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)) 
         AS result
    FROM Balans b
   WHERE idn != ''
GROUP BY idn
ORDER BY result DESC
   LIMIT 5;
```

**[Live DEMO.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9ab4/44)**

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to consider changes to your database structure, I would suggest storing the *amount* as a signed value that is positive if the *status* is 'up' and negative if the *status* is 'down'.

Under those conditions, your query would be much simpler.

```
SELECT idn, SUM(amount) as total
FROM Balans as outerB 
WHERE idn !='' AND type = 'marks'
GROUP BY idn 
ORDER BY total desc
LIMIT 5
```

However, note that this won't return records that don't have any 'marks' in the table. If you need to support that, then I think you're back to using a `CASE` operation, similar to the query in Prix's answer.